# how to extract all the names in a text using regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

English names are like the format Harry Potter, one First name the other Last name. But how to extract this kind of pattern using C++?

Comment: question is too broad. what have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: http://softwareramblings.com/2008/07/regular-expressions-in-c.html

Comment: English names are *not* like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a very simple regex would be `/\b([A-Z][a-z]+) ([A-Z][a-z]+)\b/`.

EDIT: This does not handle odd capitalisation and stray apostrophes.

EDIT: Removed `^` and `$`, placed word boundaries.

Comment: @Bo, valid point. I thought I could get away without that. Hence "very simple" :)

Comment: @Mann, I think you do not need the $ at the end since a name may not appear at the end of a line.

Comment: @Bo can you provide a more versatile regex that can match more situations of English names?

Comment: @peiti - No, sorry. I'm no good at this, just saw a couple of obvious counter examples. I know that names in general are **really** difficult, and that country and cultural borders don't apply as people move around (or the borders are changed...).

Answer (score 0):

you can start from something like this.

```
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
   // regular expression
   const std::regex pattern("([A-Z][a-z]+)\s([A-Z][a-z]+)");

   // the source text
   std::string text = "string containing names ...";

   const std::sregex_token_iterator end;
   for (std::sregex_token_iterator i(text.cbegin(), text.cend(), pattern);
        i != end;
        ++i)
   {
      std::cout << *i << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

learning regex helps.